# How can I display a survival curve with right censoring marks?

Tags: data-visualization, stata, survival

I have the following survival [data](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45635510/simple_sample.csv) and have constructed a survival plot however cannot mark the right censored points (which makes me think my survival graph is also incorrect) - how can I manage this please?

Now answered! - 
[image: survival plot]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're using Stata's `sts graph` command. It doesn't mark the censoring times by default, but [its help page](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?sts+graph) states that the `censored()` option gives three different ways of marking censoring times, depending how you want to deal with multiple individuals censored at the same timepoint.

Comment: Shouldn't this instead be on a Stata list?